# how do save customer session in magento2?

Tags: product, magento2, customer, session

I have code for test a customer session....

```
$sessionOrderBy = $this->_customerSession->setSortOrderBy('2');
echo $this->_customerSession->getSortOrderBy();
```

> return is: 2 value

after commented

```
 // $sessionOrderBy = $this->_customerSession->setSortOrderBy('2');
and run
```

> return : null;

So, how do save `$sessionOrderBy` in `_customerSession`?

Comment: are you tried saved in you controller file?

Comment: this code in Myblock. it extends product_view. so how save it? @Abdul

Answer (score 0):

Bellow code add you block file

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;


    protected $customerSession;

    protected $customerFactory;

    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function setSortOrderBy($sortOrder)
    {
        $sortOrder = 2;
        $this->customerSession->setSortOrderBy($sortOrder);
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Abdul. i tried it. when i run  `$this->customerSession->getSortOrderBy()` return Null;

Answer (score 0):

When i add

```
$this->_customerSession->regenerateId();
$sessionOrderBy = $this->_customerSession->setSortOrderBy('2');
```

it work.